# Tkinter grid_forget doesnt execute when called

Tags: python, for-loop, grid, tkinter

I am experiencing something I really don't understand. In the program, I pick a data file and then I want to hide the widgets in the window and load the data from file. But everything I tried results in first loading the file and then executing the rest...

```
def LoadProject():
    old_project = FD.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Data file","*.dat")], initialdir = "./Projects/")

    if old_project:
        napis.delete(TK.ALL)
        napis.grid_forget()
        button_new.grid_forget()
        button_load.grid_forget()

        data_file = open(old_project,"r")
        for line in data_file:
            line = line.replace("\n","")
            conv = line.split()
            data.append([float(conv[0]),int(conv[1]),float(conv[2]),float(conv[3]),float(conv[4])])
```

Everything that is before the `for` cycle is executed after the cycle finishes. Can anybody help me please? I really don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to call the `update` method of the widgets you want to forget. This will flush the pending GUI changes. From [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm):

> **update()**
>
> Processes all pending events, calls event callbacks,
>   completes any pending geometry management, redraws widgets as
>   necessary, and calls all pending idle tasks. This method should be
>   used with care, since it may lead to really nasty race conditions if
>   called from the wrong place (from within an event callback, for
>   example, or from a function that can in any way be called from an
>   event callback, etc.). When in doubt, use **update_idletasks** instead.